# Python: streaming audio and video using zeromq

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video, zeromq

I was wondering how can I stream audio and video using zmq?
I know how to stream video using it but how can I add the audio part?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use a message queue with its overhead to stream video?

Comment: what? I'm sorry but I didn't really understand your answer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP5M4lmfps4